# Can anyone help me on my Regular Expression which accepts Special character which is not required

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that includes

- At least 1 Uppercase
- At least 1 Lowercase
- At least 1 numberical
- Min of 7char

My regular expression also accepts

- At least 1 special character

But I need to make the special character available but not required.

Can anyone help me on this one.

This is my regular expression

```
 /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

I badly need help on this one.

Comment: It look like an email regex. An email should contain at least 1 special char, `@`.

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting it?

- First make a length check? >=7?
- Then check if it has minimum 1*Upper case
- Then check if it has minimum 1*Lower case
- Then check if it has minimum 1*Numerical

If any of the above is true then make valid false.

Then if special character isn't required you never need to check for it?